# How to get the containing div to stretch vertically to accommodate a floating image

Tags: css, height, css-float

Here's the basic problem:

[alt text http://img241.imageshack.us/img241/3800/problemwithfloats.png](http://img241.imageshack.us/img241/3800/problemwithfloats.png)

I want the div that holds the image to stretch vertically to accommodate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

give the div (nice rime) overflow:hidden

Comment: I ran tests in IETester with clients 6-8 and found that if IE6 compatibility is desired with this method, a width needs to be specified on the div. [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/sNG9e/1/)

Answer (score 4):

Add the following CSS formatting to the container div:

```
overflow: auto;
```

Also, it seems that you need to specify a `width` for the container div if you want the solution to work correctly in Opera and IE for Windows.

See http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html for more information.

Steve

Comment: According to the Quirksmode page I have linked to, adding a div with "clear: both" is the old solution. The newer one is to add "overflow: auto" and "width: 100%" to the container div.

Comment: In that case, you see the problem with width:100%, it might change the entire layout. Why not the simple overflow: hidden; ?

Comment: Right, I see the problem with "width: 100%"—I've modified my answer accordingly.