# Div within Div stretching

Tags: css, html

I'm designing a site, and doing a bunch of work with the styling at the moment. It has a 3 column layout (two large content columns, one small navbar column) and a few "wrapper" divs that exist just for aesthetic purposes. The HTML looks something like this:

```
<div id="out_wrapper">
    <div id="in_wrapper">
        <div id="nav"> ... content ... </div>
        <div class="column"> ... content ... </div>
        <div class="column"> ... content ... </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Each of the divs area  fixed width, but I want them to be a variable height to account for an increased amount of content. I'd like the height of the in_wrapper and out_wrapper to be slightly larger than the divs they contain, and I can't seem to get it to work. I've tried setting `min-height` instead of `height`, and removing the `height` property altogether, but I can never get in_wrapper or out_wrapper to stretch to the content. The columns stretch just fine.

Alternatively, I could set the overflow to auto and allow scrolling, which would keep the site at a fixed size, but that seems to be the less desirable outcome.

The site uses `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">` by requirement, if that makes a difference.

Comment: did you set padding on the out_wrapper and in_wrapper?

Comment: Many, many similar questions: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065408), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/992073/), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627768/). You should also look at the 960.gz, Blueprint and Object-Oriented CSS frameworks which all solve this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the height of the two wrappers to `auto` and add padding to the bottom.  Also, `overflow:hidden` if the children are floating.

```
#out_wrapper, #in_wrapper { height:auto;padding-bottom:10px;overflow:hidden;}
```

Comment: Excellent. Worked like a charm! Accepting this as soon as SE lets me.

Answer (score 2):

If a parent tag is not stretching to surround a child tag, then the child has most likely been taken out of the normal flow of the document (through float or positioning); *you need to bring the child back into the flow*. There are a few ways to do this:

Adding the style `overflow:auto` to the container element where the elements are floated.

Adding a non-semantic 'clearer' div after the floated content: `<div style="clear:both"></div>`

Making the parents a positioned element as well: `position:relative;`

Comment: +1: Didn't get me all the way to the solution, but it helped explain why I was having my problem. There were indeed some floats in there.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding a cleared div after all the columns? Like

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

That will pull the containers down to the total height. Then add some margin and/or padding to create that extra space.

Comment: While this *will* work to resolve a container around a floated element, it's unnecessary markup.  The container just needs `overflow:hidden` applied in the CSS.